# sqlAlchemy dynamic session.query remove column equivalent of add_columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

We are trying to leverage sqlAlchemy to make code more DRY, so we are using base queries to mix and match what we are trying to accomplish. We've found add_columns to be super helpful, for example

```
    books_query = (
        session.query(
            Books.author.label("author"),
            Books.title.label("title"),
            Books.genre.label("genre"),
        )
    )
```

And then later in the code we can modify it with something like

```
expanded_query = books_query.add_column(Books.publish_date.label("published"))
```

Now I'm trying to group the books query by author and genre and get a title count

```
    grouped_book_query = book_query.add_columns(
        func.count(Books.title).label("title_count"),
    ).group_by(
        Books.author, Books.genre
    )
```

But I can't figure out how to drop the original author column select or else replace it with the aggregated column.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you